# 指定したパスのツリーオブジェクトのIDを取得する方法

Tags: git

`git ls-tree -d <commit> <path>` を使用することで`path`のオブジェクトIDを含む出力を得ることができますが、オブジェクトID「のみ」を出力するコマンドは存在しないでしょうか?

また、ルートディレクトリのIDを取得するにはどうすればよいでしょう(`git ls-tree -d @ .` だと、ルートディレクトリが含むファイルについての情報が表示されます)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rev-parse <rev>:<path>
```

でどうでしょう。（`HEAD:docs/` など）また、特定コミットのツリーのルートは

```
git rev-parse <rev>^{tree}
```

で取得できます。（`HEAD^{tree}` など）

Answer (score 1):

> また、ルートディレクトリのIDを取得するにはどうすればよいでしょう

前者の「オブジェクトID「のみ」」の方はわかりませんが、後者のルートディレクトリのツリーのIDであれば、下記のように cat-file でコミットの内容を表示させればその中に含まれていると思います。

```
git cat-file commit <commit>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls-tree`とは出力単位が異なるため希望にそうかわかりませんが、

`hash-object` で指定したアイテムのオブジェクトidを取得できます。

```
git hash-object <path> [<path2> [<path3> [...]]]
```

対象はblobです。